# Check whether any of the strings from one column match any of the strings from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a situation like this:

```
lst = ["Apple", "Apple", "Apple small", "Orange", "FruitX", "FruitY"]
lst2 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Fruit1", "Fruit2"]
```

Where lst and lst2 are pandas series (or columns in a dataframe I should say).

I need to find which of the values from lst2 are in lst and in the end create a dataframe with the results as follows (ideally with the number of matched values and with the ability to also add other columns from lst ():

```
lst2     lst        match_count    other_colum_from_lstDF    other_colum_from_lstDF
Apple    Apple      2              info1                     info2
Apple    Apple      2              info1                     info2
Orange   Orange     1              info1                     info2
Fruit1   nan        0              nan                       nan
Fruit2   nan        0              nan                       nan
```

So you can match multiple values from lst to one value from lst2, so I would need the results duplicated as per above, ideally with the number of matched values.

I think the right way would be to use `isin` but wasn't able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'left', left_on = 'lst2', right_on = 'lst')
df_merge['match_count'] = df_merge.groupby(['lst'])['lst'].transform('count').fillna(0)
df_merge = df_merge[['lst2','lst','match_count','info1']]
```

Output is:

```
    lst2    lst match_count info1
0   Apple   Apple   2.0     info1
1   Apple   Apple   2.0     info1
2   Orange  Orange  1.0     info1
3   Fruit1  NaN     0.0      NaN
4   Fruit2  NaN     0.0      NaN
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm gonna have to merge on two columns, though. One is INT and one is STR for both DFs. Have two issues with that. First, it says `You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` not sure why. The other one is more complicated. If the INT is for example 5 I would like to merge on 4, 5 or 6. Basically INT - 1, INT or INT + 1. I guess I could create separate rows for these values, but I feel like there has to be a better way. In SQL it would be pretty easy.

Comment: Nevermind, I left it like that and then filtered aftewards. Thanks again

Comment: @Seminko For the first question, It is the same logic as SQL. When you merge two tables, the keys value have to be the same data type. You can change it by `df[col] = df[col].astype(...)`. However, I have no idea for the second question, sorry.